# AWS Elemental Media Live broadcast channel

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have created a channel and an input in AWS Media Live for publishing a live stream using RTP Push. I followed the documentation in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/getting-started.html. After creating the channel and running it, the channel has started successfully but the problem is

I do not know where to publish the stream and how to publish it?

I'm trying to integrate it with an iOS app to publish the stream and receive it in another end.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anything with this?

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answered this. MediaLive merely receives an input, transforms it and pushes it somewhere else. You need to give it a destination to push to which you can then pull from a client. AWS also provides MediaPackage for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your channel in `MediaLive` you specified an `Input` which contains two destinations (A and B). A is the primary and B the backup.

You have to publish your stream to the destinations (ie `rtp://ip:5000`). Please double check the `Security Group` you created for the `Input` to make sure you allow your server to push your stream.